# Fastest way to group by ID for a really big numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the best way to group 'rows' with similar IDs.

My best guess:
`np.array([test[test[:,0] == ID] for ID in List_IDs])`

result: array of arrays of arrays

```
[ array([['ID_1', 'col1','col2',...,'coln'],
         ['ID_1', 'col1','col2',...,'coln'],...,
         ['ID_1', 'col1','col2',...,'coln']],dtype='|S32')
array([['ID_2', 'col1','col2',...,'coln'],
         ['ID_2', 'col1','col2',...,'coln'],...,
         ['ID_2', 'col1','col2',...,'coln']],dtype='|S32')
....
array([['ID_k', 'col1','col2',...,'coln'],
         ['ID_k', 'col1','col2',...,'coln'],...,
         ['ID_K', 'col1','col2',...,'coln']],dtype='|S32')]
```

Can anyone suggest something that can be more efficient ?

Reminder: The `test` array is huge. 'Rows' not ordered

Comment: Have you looked at `pandas`, this has a `groupby` method designed for this

Comment: "Huge" is a relative term.  Could you be more specific? One million rows?  One hundred million?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I am now working with 300 thousand. More data to be expected

Comment: @belas Is the input array already sorted by the first column?

Comment: @Divakar the input array is in random order

Comment: Are there always the same number of rows per unique ID, or do some IDs occur more frequently than others?

Comment: @ali_m some IDs occur more frequently than others

Comment: OK, so to clarify, the output must be either a list, tuple, or np.object array,  rather than an (ids, rows, cols) homogeneous array.

Comment: @ali_m Basically I can handle both. Why would you suggest an (ids, rows, cols) homogeneous array instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming `List_IDs` is a list of all unique IDs from the first column. With that assumption, here's a Numpy-based solution -

```
# Sort input array test w.r.t. first column that are IDs
test_sorted = test[test[:,0].argsort()]

# Convert the string IDs to numeric IDs
_,numeric_ID = np.unique(test_sorted[:,0],return_inverse=True)

# Get the indices where shifts (IDs change) occur
_,cut_idx = np.unique(numeric_ID,return_index=True)

# Use the indices to split the input array into sub-arrays with common IDs
out = np.split(test_sorted,cut_idx)[1:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [305]: test
Out[305]: 
array([['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A'],
       ['B', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'B'],
       ['C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C'],
       ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
       ['B', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'E'],
       ['C', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'D']], 
      dtype='|S32')

In [306]: test_sorted
Out[306]: 
array([['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A'],
       ['B', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'B'],
       ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
       ['B', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'E'],
       ['C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C'],
       ['C', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'D']], 
      dtype='|S32')

In [307]: out
Out[307]: 
[array([['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A']], 
       dtype='|S32'), array([['B', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'B'],
        ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
        ['B', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'E']], 
       dtype='|S32'), array([['C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C'],
        ['C', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'D']], 
       dtype='|S32')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is faster than mine. Can you explain briefly why this solution is faster ? What is the key insight I should get ?

Comment: @belas Why this solution is faster than yours? I would say the fact that NumPy funcs usually are more efficient than looping with Python tools. Particularly with this solution, we are using  `np.unique` to convert the strings into numeric IDs and once we have the numeric IDs, we are in NumPy domain, because its easy to maneuver and work with them. The only bottleneck here would be the last step of splitting, because storing list of NumPy arrays isn't really an efficient method.

Comment: @belas So, takeaway msg would be to use NumPy funcs as long as possible and keep them regularly shaped. I just answered a very similar problem dealing with strings, take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33698907/3293881