# Is there a better way to determine cross-mapping indicies for numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I need the cross-mapped indicies for numpy union and intersection operations.  The code I have below works fine, but I would like to vectorize it before I apply it to large data sets.  Or, if there is a better, built in, way then what is it?

```
# ------- define the arrays and set operations ---------
A = np.array(['a','b','c','e','f','g','h','j'])
B = np.array(['h','i','j','k','m'])
C = np.union1d(A, B)
D = np.intersect1d(A,B)

# ------- get the mapped indicies for the union ----
zc = np.empty((len(C),3,))
zc[:]=np.nan
zc[:,0] = range(0,len(C))
for iy in range(0,len(C)):
    for ix in range(0, len(A)):
        if A[ix] == C[iy]:
            zc[iy,1] = ix
    for ix in range(0, len(B)):
        if B[ix] == C[iy]:
            zc[iy,2] = ix

# ------- get the mapped indicies for the intersection ----
zd = np.empty((len(D),3,))
zd[:]=np.nan
zd[:,0] = range(0,len(D))
for iy in range(0,len(D)):
    for ix in range(0, len(A)):
        if A[ix] == D[iy]:
            zd[iy,1] = ix
    for ix in range(0, len(B)):
        if B[ix] == D[iy]:
            zd[iy,2] = ix
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had checked the answer.  Yes, this was by far the most efficient solution I could find.  Unfortunately I didnt specify the question properly, as it turned out I needed a generalized solution.(not just inner and outer joins).  I am currently using a partial vector/partial loop solution but may go back to this if I can figure out how to work it into a generalized solution (cross mapping of elements between any two arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases like these, you might want to convert the strings into numerals, as working with them is far more efficient. Also, given the fact that the outputs are numeric arrays, it makes more sense to have them as numeric IDs upfront. Now, for this conversion to numeric IDs, I have seen people using `lambda` among other approaches, but I would go with [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), which is quite efficient for cases like these. Here's the implementation starting with the numeric ID conversion -

```
# ------------------------ Setup work -------------------------------
_,idx1 = np.unique(np.append(A,B),return_inverse=True)
A_ID = idx1[:A.size]
B_ID = idx1[A.size:]

# ------------------------ Union work -------------------------------
# Get length of zc, which would be the max of ID+1.
lenC = idx1.max()+1

# Initialize output array zc and fill with NaNs.
zc1 = np.empty((lenC,3,))
zc1[:]=np.nan

# Fill first column with consecutive numbers starting with 0
zc1[:,0] = range(0,lenC)

# Most important part of the code :
# Set the cols-1,2 at places specified by IDs from A and B respectively
# with values from 0 to the extent of the respective IDs
zc1[A_ID,1] = np.arange(A_ID.size)
zc1[B_ID,2] = np.arange(B_ID.size)

# ------------------------ Intersection work -------------------------------
# Get intersecting indices between A and B
intersect_ID = np.argwhere(A_ID[:,None] == B_ID)

# Initialize output zd based on the number of interesects
lenD = intersect_ID.shape[0]
zd1 = np.empty((lenD,3,))
zd1[:] = np.nan

# Fill first column with consecutive numbers starting with 0
zd1[:,0] = range(0,lenD)
zd1[:,1:] = intersect_ID
```