# broadcast intersection on a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, intersection

I am trying to generate a large 2D numpy NxN array (larr) where each cell contains the intersection (c) between lists (a or b) of string elements (director names) belonging both to the unit represented by the row (company i) and the unit represented by the column (company j). The lists (a and b) are taken from another array (marray) where companies are identified by an integer between 1 and N in the column 'nfirm'. I am not interested in the diagonal of the matrix (I substitute NaN).

I came up with the following nested loop but it is very slow and memory consuming. I was wondering whether it is possible to do it in a more efficient way by broadcasting the union operation. Any tip to improve it is very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
larr = np.empty(shape=(N,N), dtype=object)
for i in range(1,N):
   for j in range(1,N):
       a= marray['listdir'][marray['nfirm']==i].tolist()
       b= marray['listdir'][marray['nfirm']==j].tolist()
       c=np.intersect1d(a,b)
       if (len(c)>0 and (i!=j)):
           larr[i,j]=c
       else:
           larr[i,j]='NaN'
       del a, b, c
```

Comment: See if [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698592/is-there-a-better-way-to-determine-cross-mapping-indicies-for-numpy-arrays) helps.

Comment: Thanks Divakar, the reindexing part improves the speed

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvement: `a` is recomputed `j` times but independent of `j`:

```
larr = np.empty(shape=(N, N), dtype=object)
for i in range(1, N):
    a = marray['listdir'][marray['nfirm']==i].tolist()
    for j in range(1, N):
        b = marray['listdir'][marray['nfirm']==j].tolist()
        c = np.intersect1d(a,b)
        if len(c) > 0 and i != j:
            larr[i, j] = c
        else:
            larr[i, j] = 'NaN'
        del b
    del a
del c
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly,

`marray['listdir']` is a list of string representing directors, indexed by movie.

`marray['nfirm']` is a list of integers representing companies, also indexed by movie.

You want to create a matrix of directors that have been shared by pairs of companies.

To be more efficient, you can first build a dictionary linking companies to movies, then build the matrix:

```
firm_movies = [[] for _ in xrange(N)]
for i, m in enumerate(marray['nfirm']):
    firm_movies[m].append(i)

larr = np.empty(shape=(N, N), dtype=object)
for i in xrange(N):
    larr[i, i] = 'NaN'
    for j in xrange(i+1, N):
       a = marray['listdir'][firm_movies[i]]
       b = marray['listdir'][firm_movies[j]]
       c = np.intersect1d(a,b)
       larr[i, j] = larr[j, i] = c if len(c)>0 else 'NaN'
```

Comment: Sorry Peter, I should have specified I am looking at company's executives (i.e., directors) rather than movie directors. Accordingly, lists of directors in marray['listdir'] are indexed by company (the company index is in marray['nfirm'])